# ceph fs mount error

Tags: 12.04, mount, cluster, ceph

I want to mount ceph fs with the kernel driver, but when I excute below command on my admin node

```
mount -t ceph 192.168.0.164:6789:/ /mnt/mycephfs
```

it return below error

```
mount error 5 = Input/output error
```

and dmesg output is:

```
libcph: mon0 192.168.0.164:6789 feature set mismatch, my 8a < server's 4204008a, missing 42040000
libcph: mon0 192.168.0.164:6789 missing requird protocol features
```

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) and my kernel version is 3.2.0-98 and I use latest ceph release for precise (0.94.6)

Comment: What is the distribution and kernel version you are running on the servers? Could it be related to [this](http://lists.ceph.com/pipermail/ceph-users-ceph.com/2013-October/005540.html)?

Comment: all of my nodes and admin and monitors are precise with kernel 3.2.0-98

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance that your firewall on the monitor host is blocking 6789 and 6800.  I had this problem just recently that that was my issue.

Comment: I try that on proxmox and I receive this error, but then I do this test on VMware Worksation and it works fine

Comment: I am not familiar with Proxmox so I can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tune cephs to support old clients:

```
osd crush tunables legacy|argonaut|bobtail|firefly|hammer|jewel|optimal|default :  set crush tunables values to <profile>
```

this should be done on ceph node.